# My App not shown in market using ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, google-play

i have application on the market for more than 5 months, and i bought tablet with ice cream os, so i became stunned when notice my app not shown for ice cream os, so i tried to fix it

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

but the application still not appearing, any helpful hints?

---

**Update**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
```

My tablet doesn't have GPS, but contains "Google Location Service"

---

**Update**

My Manifest file :

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
```

and still the app not appearing on the market!!

---

**Update**

**Screen layouts**: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE

**Required device features**

android.hardware.screen.portrait

android.hardware.touchscreen

android.permission.INTERNET

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**This application is available to over 0 devices.**

---

**problem solved, the final Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Now the app appears on search list for Ice Cream :)**

**thank you guys for help :)**

Comment: Maybe you use a permission or a feature that your tablet doesn't have? The developthingy tells you what is used to "filter devices".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you study this page : [uses feature element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), you will see that a *uses-permission*  element in a manifest  may **imply** that a certain hardware feature is **required**.

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is one of those permissions, so it will only show as available for devices with a GPS

Comment: i fixed them, and uploaded it, i think i should wait a while, to see if it works or not :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `<supports-screens>` instead of `<compatible-screens>`

More information on [Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Comment: do `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />` covers all sizes?

Comment: Density and screen sizes are different. If you want to cover all sizes, make all of the sizes (`android:smallScreens` to `android:xlargeScreens`) true in `<supports-screens>`.

Comment: i fixed them, and uploaded it, i think i should wait a while, to see if it works or not :)

Comment: Your updated manifest looks pretty fine, unless there is something else that you have not shown. The next suspect would be the device itself. If it is a developer device or an unreleased device, as per [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html), apps marked as copy protected will not be visible on them. I would also recommend viewing the "Supported Devices -> Show devices" in the developer console to look for any clues.