# Android: app invisible to tablets on google playstore

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've published my app on google playstore, the app is now visible to phones, but I cannot see it with my tablet(Nexus /). Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.application.myapp"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity.......>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I make it visible to tablets?

Comment: For how long have you been waiting? I was facing similar issues with different devices that had been resolved after a waiting a while (4+ hours). P.s.: I think there is nothing wrong with your manifest.

Comment: Make sure you have to disable or enable some permissions like wifi, bluetooth, and so on... Based on these too the device may not be recognized.

Comment: maybe one of my permission is not available on tablets?

Comment: should not be what is causing you trouble but android:targetSdkVersion="13" /> is way too low for may 2013. we are already at 17, with 18 coming this week..

Comment: @Trinimon...maybe your answer is correct, because I can see my device on developer console within the compatible devices list...

Comment: see my question here and the whole answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173068/my-app-not-shown-in-market-using-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: @MoshErsan thank you, I added <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/> because "telephony" function appears in the developer console (maybe due to one of my permissions).
I'll try to republish now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Stack Overflow question is very similar to yours. It suggests that besides screen sizes, you should make sure that your permissions and features are all things that the particular device can use. (For example, setting the camera feature would cause devices without cameras to be excluded.)

[Manifest and supported devices showed in Android market - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225580/manifest-and-supported-devices-showed-in-android-market?rq=1)

Comment: I will try with all permissions set to required=false

Comment: My suspected is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
maybe this is not  a tablet feature?

Comment: If your tablet can access a wireless (cell) network, then ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE would be a valid permission. Perhaps READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? A phone can use external storage, but I don't think the tablet can.

Comment: maybe this could suggest something: the developer console says that my application has android.hardware.TELEPHONY function. Obviously my tablet does not have this function...but where is the point where i defined this?

Comment: I think you need to work on your search skills. Check out this page here on Stack Overflow where eMich suggests setting android:required = "false" for telephony. This makes it optional, allowing non-telephone-related devices to see your app. -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420228/android-market-filters-app-telephony

Comment: yes, I solved setting uses-feature telephony with required=false.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it's the WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission. Requesting it only worked on older devices, nowadays (>= Android 4.0 I think) it is only granted to system apps.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but:
-The phones <4.0 can see the app on the playstore
-I've published the app yesterday with all permission required=false and nothing changed...